# how to trim css code to just one line

Tags: html, css

My client is fussy about his website loading speed. I think one way is to trim css code to just one line. For example:

```
tr th{
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    text-align: left;
}
tr th, tr td{
    padding: 9px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

to

```
tr th{border-bottom: 1px solid;text-align: left;}tr th, tr td{padding: 9px 20px;border-right: 1px solid;}
```

How do you guys normal trim it? I use dreamweaver to write css code.

Also, I found Youtube's css link is like "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-home-c4-2x-vflt3qrMn.css", is there benefits? Cheers.

Comment: I use LESS, with the setting enabled to strip unnecessary whitespace. In the absence of a processor, you could just strip out all tabs and newlines.

Comment: read this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx

Comment: In all honesty, if your client is that fussy regarding website loading speed, there are other areas you could look into which could yield more noticeable results.

Comment: The article above is so helpful. Thx heaps.

Comment: Minifying CSS has practically no effect on a web site's loading speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use CSS Minifier - online.
Link :[CSS Minifier](http://cssminifier.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a problem that can be solved by a program. At least, not easily.

For instance, I could reduce your CSS to this:

```
tr>*{padding:9px 20px;border-right:1px solid}tr>th{border-bottom:1px solid;text-align:left}
```

Notice how I changed `tr th, tr td` to just `tr>*`, since `th` and `td` are the only valid children of a `tr`. No CSS minifier can make that kind of optimisation.

Also notice that you can't just blindly strip out whitespace, for instance `1px solid` needs that space there.